# How to call a controller method from a link in rails 3

Tags: ruby

```
<%= form_tag home_action_path, method: :post do %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Call Action' %>
<% end %>
```

I want it like

```
<%= link_to 'Call Action', home_action_path, method: :post %>
```

OR

```
<%= button_to 'Call Action', home_action_path, method: :post %>
```

I have a method which needs to be called EXACTLY once, and since this is only the experimental phase, I decided that a simple button should suffice. However, I can't seem to find out how to / if I can simply call the method from a button click.

The method is in home_controller.rb and the button is in index.html.erb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't call methods on controllers, you send requests to URLs/endpoints in your application, which result in controller methods being invoked.

What's wrong with what you posted?

```
<%= link_to 'Call Action', home_action_path, method: :post %>
```

That seems fine.